# Django: how to create custom "base" model

Tags: python, django, django-models

In almost all my tables (= classes of `models.Model`) I have three `DateTimeField`:

- creation
- validity start
- validity end

Is there a way to have a "base" model class where I declare those fields, and make all my other model extend this one? I couldn't find a valuable answer on the Web.

Comment: Yes. [Model Inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/models/#model-inheritance)

Answer (score 63, accepted):

**You need to create an abstract base class having these common fields and then inherit this base class in your models.**

**Step-1: Create a new [Abstract Base Class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes)**

We first create an abstract base class called `BaseModel`. This `BaseModel` class contains the 3 model fields `creation_date`, `valididity_start_date` and `validity_end_date` which are common in almost every model of yours.

In the inner `Meta` class, we set `abstract=True`. This model will then not be used to create any database table. Instead, when it is used as a base class for other models, its fields will be added to those of the child class.

```
class BaseModel(models.Model):  # base class should subclass 'django.db.models.Model'

    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(..) # define the common field1
    validity_start_date = models.DateTimeField(..) # define the common field2
    validity_end_date = models.DateTimeField(..) # define the common field3

    class Meta:
        abstract=True # Set this model as Abstract
```

**Step-2: Inherit this Base class in your models**

After creating the abstract base class `BaseModel`, we need to inherit this class in our models. This can be done using normal inheritance as done in Python.

```
class MyModel1(BaseModel): # inherit the base model class

    # define other non-common fields here
    ...

class MyModel2(BaseModel): # inherit the base model class

    # define other non-common fields here
    ...
```

Here, `MyModel1` and `MyModel2` classes contain the 3 fields `creation_date`, `valididity_start_date` and `validity_end_date` from the base class `BaseModel` apart from the other model fields defined in it.

Comment: Any chance you could also recommend a specific folder structure for handling these common models?

Comment: What I normally do when I have helpers or functionality that will cross between apps I create an app called `core`. This can hold helpers, mixins, base models, etc... so then I can just do `from core.models import BaseModel`, etc..

Comment: @ChristopherGrande beginner in Django here, sorry, if this will sound like a dumb question. Do you also create the `core` directory via `python manage,py startapp core`? Or can I simply add folder containing the model.py file? Thank you

Comment: @fearfox yes, I create an entire `core` app using the `startapp` command. Then I put core views, or other utils in there as well.

Answer (score 12):

```
class Basetable(models.Model):

   created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
   modified_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
   created_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='%(class)s_createdby')
   modified_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                                related_name='%(class)s_modifiedby', null=True, blank=True)

   class Meta:
       abstract = True
```

This way you can define your model and extend Basetable to other model class

Answer (score 0):

This way you can define your model and extend the Base model to other model classes. I hope this will help you to make a clean and reusable architecture for your Django-based project.

```
class ActiveManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().filter(active=True).order_by('- 
        created_at')


class InactiveManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().filter(active=False)


class BaseModel(models.Model):
    """
    Used in all the models as base
    """
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True,
                             blank=True,
                             help_text='If this object is active')

    active_objects = ActiveManager()
    inactive_objects = InactiveManager()
    objects = models.Manager()
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, 
                 on_delete=models.SET_NULL,related_name='%. 
                 (class)s_created_by', null=True, blank=True,)
    updated_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                 related_name='%(class)s_updated_by', 
                 on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
                 null=True, blank=True,)

class Meta:
    abstract = True
```